# Decrypt stored secret using HTTPS transport

Tags: security, encryption, ssl, https, openssl

I am considering developing a software for safely storing files on a server.

Let's say I have a secret document initially stored on my client computer that I want to upload to the server. The requirements here is that the file on the server should be encrypted at all times and since the private key is on the client, it is unreadable for anyone accessing the server directly. Maybe I can do it with javascript or maybe I need to develop a full fledged app to handle the upload. Either way is OK but I need to be able to download and decrypt the file using web browser only.

This got me thinking. Can I configure HTTPS (SSL) in a way that I can precalculate the encrypted response from server to client. In that case I can do that while uploading and when the document is requested I can just return the pre-encrypted data which will be decrypted by the SSL stack on the client.

I know that the there will be a random number exchange that prevents this. But is there a way to configure SSL so that the response from server to client will be the same always. In this case replay attacks from server to client is acceptable and not an issue.

Comment: I'm wondering why the you don't just decrypt after getting it from the server? Ie. Download (http or https either is fine as doc is encrypted with a client key) and then decrypt it once downloaded. It's seems like an over engineered solution otherwise. Of course your requirements may be different.

Comment: The idea is to have the web browser do the decryption and as I see it using SSL for decryption is the only way without web browser plugins? I have seen javascript implementations, problem is where on the client to store the private certificate since the javascript implementation does not have access to the cert store on the client.

Comment: Why are browser extension out if may ask?

Comment: Mainly because I need it to be accessible from any browser. Even in environments where there is no access to install addons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an SSL handshake, the client generates the pre-master secret that will be used to derive the session key. Since you appear to have control only over the server, you cannot prevent the client from steering the conversation in a particular (cryptographic) direction.